# How to get attribute value from options in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck in one of unique functionality using select box. Html is like:

```
<select name="hello" id="hello" >
   <option selected="selected" value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
    <option data-att="one">abc</option>
    <option data-att="one">sd</option>
    <option data-att="one">wer</option>
    <option data-att="two">uio</option>
    <option data-att="two">abc</option>
    <option data-att="two">sd</option>
    <option data-att="three">wer</option>
    <option data-att="three">tyu</option>       
</select>
```

Now I want to make an array of that data-att values from this select box without selected, LIKE :

`var arr = new Array();
 arr=['one','two','three'];`

It will run on window load state it will use for another dropdown dynamic values after window load. But I want data-att value once which from the same attribute.

Comment: can you explain a bit more the statement is a bit confusing..you want to get all the option data attr not only the selected one?

Comment: edited thanks for quick reply

Comment: You want a multiple selected value or single selected values

Comment: why do you need `data-att` for options ? cant you use `value` attribute

Comment: are all of your `data-att` values are like this mean is there any possibility than `one` will come after `two` or `three` something like that

Comment: i already accept the answer which is helpful for me and that is correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arr=[];
$('#hello option').each(function(){
  if($.inArray($(this).attr('data-att'), arr) == -1) { //check if id value not exits than add it
    arr.push($(this).attr('data-att'))
    
    }


})
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="hello" id="hello">
  <option selected="selected" value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
  <option data-att="one">abc</option>
  <option data-att="one">sd</option>
  <option data-att="one">wer</option>
  <option data-att="two">uio</option>
  <option data-att="two">abc</option>
  <option data-att="two">sd</option>
  <option data-att="three">wer</option>
  <option data-att="three">tyu</option>
</select>
```

Use `$.inArray()` to check if value exist in array if not add on arr

will give you `[undefined, "one", "two", "three"]`

```js
var arr = [];
$('#hello option').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-att')) {
    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('data-att'), arr) == -1) { //check if id value not exits than add it
      arr.push($(this).attr('data-att'))

    }
  }



})
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="hello" id="hello">
  <option selected="selected" value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
  <option data-att="one">abc</option>
  <option data-att="one">sd</option>
  <option data-att="one">wer</option>
  <option data-att="two">uio</option>
  <option data-att="two">abc</option>
  <option data-att="two">sd</option>
  <option data-att="three">wer</option>
  <option data-att="three">tyu</option>
</select>
```

You can add additional If statement to make sure only option with attr `data-att` will be counted

Comment: Thanks a lot dear awesome answer

Answer (score 2):

Unsure of what you want, but you can iterate through each of the options in the select list and if that value is not yet in the array - push that data-att into an array. If you want all of them to be pushed - remove the indexOf and just push each dataAtt.

```
var newArray=[];
$('#hello option').each(function(){
    var dataAtt = $(this).attr('data-att');
    if(newArray.indexOf( dataAtt  == -1){
      newArray.push(dataAtt)};
})
```

Comment: it gives multiple values but i need only one time append in an array same like first answer

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using jQuery you could call the forEach method to an object like this:

```js
var options = document.querySelectorAll("#hello option");
var attributes = [];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function(item, index, array){
  attributes.push(item.getAttribute('data-att'));
});

console.log(attributes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get this done in single line using jquery map function,this thing act as a each function where value gets added to the array each time and prints the things finally...

```
var arr =  $.map($('#hello option'), function (item, index) { return $(item).attr('data-att') });

console.log(uniqueArr(arr));


function uniqueArr(arr) {
var result = [];
$.each(arr, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
});
return result;
}
```

Comment: I missed out in removing the duplicate value in the array,now i have modified the code to achieve your needs..